# how to use wget and not preserve date?

Tags: wget

When I do a wget I want the file saved in my filesystem to have the date of the download, which is now, not the date on the server. So when I do:

```
ll -ltr
```

I want the file to show at the end of the list (the newest file).

And how I make this the default? And when it's the default, how I do get back to the wget default?

Comment: "perserve"? Is it something between *preserve* and *perverse*? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `--no-use-server-timestamps` option to tell Wget not to copy the server's timestamp locally.

To make that the default, add the line:

```
use_server_timestamps = no
```

to `~/.wgetrc`.

Comment: thanks, how I make it a default ? and when is default, how I do the default of wget ?

Comment: @Sérgio Updated the answer with the additional info.

Comment: Huh. Didn't know there was a `wgetrc`. Learned something new today :)

Comment: @DennisMeng But of course - what good would a Unix program be without its accompanying programrc? :)

Comment: Just too used to defaults I guess. :P (But seriously, good to know; not used to Unix myself)

Comment: For those looking for the opposite, then it's `wget --timestamping` as seen here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/198238

Answer (score 2):

"By default, when a file is downloaded, its timestamps are set to match those from the remote file. This allows the use of it was actually downloaded; for that purpose, the --no-use-server-timestamps option has been provided."

```
wget --no-use-server-timestamps [URL]
```